# literal-conversion warning in union of structs

Tags: c, warnings, unions

I try to wrap multiple `struct`s in an `union` and access the structure using the macro `SET`. This macro sets the structure's field based on the given type `t`, which is an `enum` constant.

When I compile the below code with clang 12.0.0 I see the following  `-Wliteral-conversion` warning:

```
union.c:46:19: warning: implicit conversion from 'float' to 'int' changes value from 1.3 to 1 [-Wliteral-conversion]
        SET (num, FLOAT, 1.3f);
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
union.c:31:14: note: expanded from macro 'SET'
                u.ni.val = v;                           \
                     ~ ^
```

This behaviour occurs whenever I call `SET` with `float` values, for example,

```
SET (num, FLOAT, 1.3f);
```

However, the code compiles without warning when I write the `switch` block from the definition of `SET` to the `main` function.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
/* Compile with:
 * cc -Wall -std=c17
 */
#include <stdio.h>

enum numer_type { VOID, INT, FLOAT };

union Number {
    struct {
        int type;
    } n;
    
    struct {
        int type;
        int val;
    } ni;

    struct {
        int type;
        float val;
    } nf;
};

#define SET(u, t, v) switch (t) {   \
    case VOID:                      \
        u.n.type = t;               \
        break;                      \
                                    \
    case INT:                       \
        u.ni.type = t;              \
        u.ni.val = v;               \
        break;                      \
                                    \
    case FLOAT:                     \
        u.nf.type = t;              \
        u.nf.val = v;               \
        break;                      \
                                    \
    default:                        \
        puts ("Unknown");           \
}

int main (void)
{
    union Number num;
    SET (num, FLOAT, 1.3f);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The compiler message says the problem occurs on line 64, but you have only shown us 50 lines of code. Always show exactly the messages for exactly the code you are showing.

Comment: @Eric The 'extra' lines are created when the macro 'call' for `SET` (in `main`) is expanded.

Comment: @AdrianMole: Compiler messages report physical line numbers of the source file, not lines from macro expansion. They need to do this so that the numbers are useful for finding the locations in the source code.

Comment: @Eric OK. I was just working through the code myself and saw that. But for posting my first comment, I *may* have 'beaten' you to posting an answer. :-) Still, no worries...

Comment: Also, your example code uses a `double` literal, but the error message is for a `float` literal. This particular case was easily solved, but mismatches can easily interfere with problem diagnosis. Computers are exact machines. If you want to work with them, you should practice being exact too.

Comment: There is also a superfluous `;` after your `SET` call. This will give a warning if all warnings are enabled: **warning : empty expression statement has no effect; remove unnecessary ';' to silence this warning [-Wextra-semi-stmt]**

Comment: @AdrianMole, even if I compile with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`, clang 12.0.0 does not produce a warning on that semicolon.

Answer (score 3):

In the code resulting from the expansion of `SET(num, FLOAT, 1.3)`, the line `u.ni.val = v;` in the `INT` case assigns a `double` literal `1.3` to the `int` member `u.ni.val`. Although this code is never executed due to the `switch` on `t`, the compiler does not know this and issues a warning.

You could avoid the warning by changing the assignment to `u.ni.val = (int) v;`.